# IE8 background image is not showing correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I used  http://css3pie.com/ while creating my button for IE8 here is my code

```
.mybutton


{
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #135496;
    background: url("../img/arrow_white.png"),-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#135496), to(#12408d))no-repeat !important;
    background: url("../img/arrow_white.png"),-webkit-linear-gradient(#135496,
#12408d)no-repeat !important;
    background: url("../img/arrow_white.png"),-moz-linear-gradient(#135496,
#12408d)no-repeat !important;
    background: url("../img/arrow_white.png"), -ms-linear-gradient(#135496, #12408d)no-repeat !important;
    background: url("../img/arrow_white.png"),-o-linear-gradient(#135496,
#12408d)no-repeat !important;
    background: url("../img/arrow_white.png"), linear-gradient(#135496, #12408d)no-repeat !important;
    -pie-background: url("../img/arrow_white.png"), linear-gradient(#135496, #12408d)no-repeat !important;
    behavior: url("../img/PIE.htc");
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    filter: none !important; }
```

but it repeats background image though I set it to no-repeat. Also if I remove pie-background the background image is not repeating instead the gradient is missing.
What am i doing wrong here ? And does pie support background gradient and background-image at the same time?

Comment: why don't you try to move the background image to a child span and apply the css to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a separate rule, to keep the no-repeat value for all images, like this: `background-repeat:no-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use like this:

```
url("../img/arrow_white.png"), linear-gradient(#135496, #12408d)no-repeat !important;
```

But use like this:

```
url("../img/arrow_white.png") no-repeat, linear-gradient(#135496, #12408d) !important;
```

Comment: !important should be in the end            url("../img/arrow_white.png") no-repeat, linear-gradient(#135496, #12408d)!important;